# How to make non-modal stage appear always on top of JavaFx fullscreen stage

Tags: javafx, window, fullscreen

I have

- a primary stage which the user can configure to be in fullscreen mode
- secondary stages (tool windows) which the user can open. These windows should be always on top the the primary stage (regardless of whether its in fullscreen mode or not).

The latter does not work, even if I use `setAlwaysOnTop(true)` for the secondary stages they will disappear behind the primary stage once the user clicks on the primary stage.
This only happens when the primary stage is in full screen mode, everything works fine if the primary stage is not in fullscreen mode.
How can I enable this concept of tools windows in front of a fullscreen stage? Example code:

```
public class Test extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        Button button1 = new Button("New Tool Window");
        button1.setOnAction((e) -> {
            Stage toolStage = new Stage();
            Scene toolScene = new Scene(new Label("Am I on top?"), 300, 250);
            toolStage.setScene(toolScene);
            toolStage.initOwner(stage);
            toolStage.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
            toolStage.show();
        });

        Button button2 = new Button("Close");
        button2.setOnAction((e) -> System.exit(0));

        vbox.getChildren().addAll(button1, button2);
        stage.show();
        stage.setFullScreen(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Update 8/20/2016:** Confirmed as a bug: [JDK-8164210](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8164210)

Answer (score 0):

A way to bypass this limitation is to:
Deactivate fullscreen mode
Create a keyCombination for psuedo fullscreen
Set the stage style undecorated and not resizable
Se the screen to the size of the user screen and position it at 0,0.

It is easy to create your own border for minimizing and closing the program as shown here:

[JavaFX Stage.setMaximized only works once on Mac OSX (10.9.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38599588/javafx-stage-setmaximized-only-works-once-on-mac-osx-10-9-5/38606533#38606533)

And here:

[JavaFX 8 Taskbar Icon Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616483/javafx-8-taskbar-icon-listener/38616956#38616956)

Comment: To use this I would have to rebuild the primary stage? Because I cannot modify the stage style with the initStyle method once it has been set to visible. And unfortunately if I rebuild the stage I also need to rebuild all the tool stages because their owner has now changed to the new stage, and initOwner can also not called once the stage is shown.

Comment: @timm Have yo try calling toFront on the stage you want to keep on the front? Mayb calling it with a scene click handler or when the primary stage goes to fullscreen? Anyways hope you figure it out man! Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to set initmodality after set initowner

```
toolStage.initOwner(stage);
toolStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
```